# How to formally write this statement on the existence of the limits?

Tags: calculus, logic, foundations

> The existence of the limit from one side does not entail the existence of the limit from the other side.

(Source: Schaum's Outline of Calculus, 6th Edition, by F. Ayres, ‎E. Mendelson, p. 57)

How would you, using the precise definitions of the limits, formally write the above statement?

The precise definitions of the left-hand limit and the right-hand limits according to this [source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjJhrWjjr3tAhUNY8AKHUE3CMcQFjAJegQIHBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kkuniyuk.com%2FCalcBook%2FCalcNotes0207.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2k6jCzfSyi6373DyknPs0_) are as follows:
[image]

Comment: Do you have any ideas? What about thinking about negating a conditional statement?

Answer (score 1):

If we denote the statements "$\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)$ exists" and "$\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)$ exists" as they are, then your statement can be symbolized as follows

$$\neg\left(\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)\text{ exists}\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)\text{ exists}\right)\wedge\neg\left(\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)\text{ exists}\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)\text{ exists}\right)$$

Equivalently, by DeMorgan's,

$$\neg\left[\left(\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)\text{ exists}\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)\text{ exists}\right)\vee\left(\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)\text{ exists}\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)\text{ exists}\right)\right]$$

**Edit**: We can further reveal the logical structure of the statement by making use of the following definitions:

1. $\lim\limits_{x\to a^{\pm}}f(x)\text{ exists}\iff\left(\exists L\in\mathbb{R}\right)\left(\lim\limits_{x\to a^{\pm}}f(x)=L\right)$
2. $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f(x)=L\iff(\forall\varepsilon>0)\{(\exists\delta >0)[(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})(a<x<a+\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon)]\}$
3. $\lim\limits_{x\to a^-}f(x)=L\iff(\forall\varepsilon>0)\{(\exists\delta >0)[(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})(a-\delta<x<a\Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon)]\}$

Similar definitions hold for left-hand limits.

I won't present the fully expanded statement here; it's way too big and messy.

Comment: Thanks. Look at the precise definitions I added to the Q. How would you write your answer using them? How would you symbolize the verb "exist"? By an existential quantifier?

Comment: @Juya check out my edited post. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Given a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and some fixed $x_0 \in X$, the existence of

$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^-} f(x)$

does not guarantee the existence of

$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^+} f(x)$

and vis versa.